# How to set difference of date to "0" when two date is same date

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have three fields. Two field with two dates. Another field for total remaining days using "Computed for display". Both dates use to calculate the difference between both two and get the remaining date. For the START date I'm using @Now to get everyday current date when open the document. For my END date, is editable field set by User. As seen below figure, the start date is exceed end date.

[image: monitor]

What I want is when start date is same with end date, it stop update and remaining day becom "0". 
I don't know whether this is possible or not. If it possible, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Use @Today if you're not interested in the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@Date](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_DATE.html) to eliminate the time part of date time value.

This way

```
@Date(StartDate) - @Date(EndDate)
```

will be 0 if start and end date have the same date.

In case that fields can be empty or strings use a formula like this:

```
@If(StartDate = "" | EndDate = ""; ""; @Date(@ToTime(StartDate)) - @Date(@ToTime(EndDate)))
```

Comment: I think he wants it to not go negative, as well, so probably @If(@Date(startDate)-@Date(endDate) < 0; 0; @Date(StartDate)-@Date(EndDate)).

Comment: Okay, will try it later. Thank you for your answers. I will try it first.

Comment: You can shorten that to @Abs(@Date(StartDate)-@Date(EndDate))

Comment: Hey, I already try all solution but it show error message: "Field 'PMonitorWarranty': Incorrect data type for operator or @Function: Time/Date expected"

Comment: This happens when the field is empty or a string.